# Is it possible to set the exact property on a react-router Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have a dynamic route configured to be set up to handle modals as follows:

```
const DynamicRoute = ({ exact, path, isAsync, isAbstract, isPrivate, Component, modal, ...rest }) =>
  <Route
    exact={!!modal.active ? false : exact} path={!!modal.active ? `${modal.path}` : path}
    render={({ history, location, match }) => (
      <Component
        match={match}
        isAsync={isAsync}
        isAbstract={isAbstract}
        history={history}
        isPrivate={isPrivate}
        location={location}
        modal={modal}
        {...rest}
      />
    )}
  />
```

Which is being wrapped by a Switch that takes a modal from Redux:

```
const ActionContainer = ({modal}) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <DynamicRoute exact path='/' modal={modal} Component={LandingModule} />
      <Route exact path='/profile' mod={ProfileModule} />
    </Switch>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ modal }: Object) => ({
  modal
})
```

The Landing module looks like this:

```
const LandingModule = ({modal}) =>
  <div className='landing-container'>
    <Header inverted />
    {/* Content */}
    {/* Intro */}
    {!!modal.active ? <Route path={`${modal.path}`} component={modal.modal} /> : ''}
  </div>
```

The issue I am having with this is that if I set `exact` to true on the outer Route, then it seems like react-router has cached this and will not render the route whenever the `modal` is set in the store. If I do not set `exact`, the modal is rendered correctly (even as the URL is changed to reflect the new path.)

Is `exact` indeed a fixed value after `Route` creation? If so, is there a cleaner/conventional way to do this?!

What I want to achieve is avoiding `LondingModule` getting rendered on any other path, but allow for a login or registration (or any future) modal to pop up over the LandingModule. And unfortunately, without `exact`, it renders on every path.

Comment: Yeah I think setting `exact` on the outer Route is your problem. Seems like it shouldn't exist on the outer Router if you are changing it inside the `DynamicRoute` function anyway though.

Comment: But the issue, again, is that if I do not set it on the Route, then it will match for everything.

Comment: I gave up on this approach, as it seems `exact` is cached and immutable by design. I have gone with a hash-based route instead.